# Trying to prove delta function is 0 outside of 0

Tags: integration, limits, dirac-delta

The delta function can be defined as follow:

$$\delta (x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int dk e^{ikx}$$

I am trying to prove that $\delta$ is equal to $0$ for $x\neq 0$

So I tried to replace the integral over infinity by an integral between $K$ and $-K$ (and then take the limit $K\rightarrow \infty$)

Let $x\neq 0$,

$$\delta(x) = \lim_{K \to \infty} \frac{e^{iKx} - e^{-iKx}}{2\pi ix}$$

$$ = \lim_{K \to \infty} \frac{2sin(Kx)}{2\pi x}$$
$$ = \lim_{K \to \infty} \frac{Ksin_c(Kx)}{\pi }$$

But this doesn't seem to converge to $0$.

Where is the error? Isn't it OK to replace the infinite integral with $K$ variable bound ? Or did I go wrong somewhere else? This delta function is puzzling me

Comment: In the last step you should have the $K$ in the denominator, not the numerator. This is because the $x$ is the denominator of the $\sin_c$ function.

Comment: @CyclotomicField No, the last step is correct; $K/K=1$.

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem): $|\sin Kx|\le1$ constrains $\left|\frac{\sin Kx}{\pi x}\right|$.

Comment: @J.G. I'm missing the point to your hint. It can't be a hint for how to show that integral vanishes, but I can't guess what else it might be...

Comment: I was only addressing the limit being $0$ for each $x\ne0$, not $\int_{\Bbb R}\delta (x)=1$. The OP's limit is proportional to $\int_{-K}^Ke^{ikx}dk$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "delta function" is not a function. In particular there is no such thing as $\delta(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb R$, so that integral formula at the start is nonsense.

There *are* true facts analogous to that intgeral formula and to what you're trying to prove, but we need to be much more careful about the definitions.

Say $V=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

> > **True Fact 1.** $\delta$ vanishes in $V$.

That does **not** mean that $\delta(x)=0$ for all $x\in V$; that's nonsense. It means that $\langle\delta,\phi\rangle:=\phi(0)=0$ for all smooth $\phi$ supported in $V$.

And now for each $k$ let $e_k$ be the tempered distribution corresponding to the function $e^{ikx}$: $$\langle e_k,\phi\rangle:=\int\phi(x)e^{ikx}\,dx.$$

> > **True Fact 2.** $\delta=\frac1{2\pi}\int e_k\,dk$.

What that means is explained by saying it's a vector-valued, in particular an $\mathscr S'(\Bbb R)$-valued, integral. What *that* means in turn is a long story, sorry. But TF 2 definitely does *not* mean $$\delta(k)=\frac1{2\pi}\int e^{ikx}\,dx.\quad(*)$$Someone somewhere wanted to state TF 2, but explaining what it actually means was too advanced, so they settled for (*) instead. They lied when they did that.

Comment: I don't understand why your inner product is $$\langle e_k,\phi\rangle:=\int\phi(x)e^{ikx}\,dx.$$

Comment: I thought the standard inner product was $$\langle e_k,\phi\rangle:=\int\phi(x)e^{-ikx}\,dx.$$

Comment: that's not an inner product. $\delta$ is a "distribution". That means it's a ("continuous") linear ,map from a certain space $\mathscr S$ to $\Bbb C$. So one might write $\delta(\phi)$ for the value of $\delta$ at the point $\phi\in\mathscr S$. People who don't like that notation often use the inner-product-ish notation to mean the same thing

Comment: I also don't understand why $\phi (0) = 0$ in your example... That doesn't look too trivial to me

Comment: Does "smooth" mean that the function has $0$ value at $x=0$ ?

Comment: no, but saying $\phi$ is supported in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ does say that $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: Hi, I think I now understand what TF1 means ($\delta$ distribution takes the averages of all the points around $0$). On the other hand, I don't get to find informations about the tempered distribution of exponentials that you mentioned. Is there a name for that distribution (so I can search for it in internet)?

Comment: No, that's not what TF 1 means. What it means is exactly what the sentence following the statement says it means. What information about that $e_k$ are you looking for? (If you want to understand this you're going to have learn some real analysis first - looking for this fact and then that fact on the internet is not going to lead to an actual understanding of a large and totally new branch of math...)

Comment: In many parts of Internet (including research papers), there are things like $\int f(t) \delta (t) dt $ It goes in contradiction with what you said _there is no such thing as δ(x) for  x∈R_ ?

Comment: The thing I wanted to know about $e_k$ was: are all the $e_k$ one distribution or is there one distribution per $e_k$ ?

Comment: Yes, in many places on the internet or in course notes you can find expressions like $\int f(x)\delta(x)$. That notation is simply wrong. Each $e_k$ is a distribution. I don't know whether or not that means "there is one distribution per $e_k$"; that sounds like saying there's one real number per real number...

Comment: In $(*)$ there's a typo with overload of notation; one of the $k$'s or $x$'s should be switched.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thx. Curious - the point to (*) is to say that it's false; given that it's amusing that you were able to tell it wasn't what i meant, heh heh

Comment: Yes well, dummy indices are something which I'm sure *you* wouldn't have a real mathematical issue with :) Also, context helps... in your previous two integrals this mistake wasn't present.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thinking about it, the irony was only apparent; the fact that I meant to say (*) was false really has nothing to do with the need to state it clearly.